# Entity framework 4.0 getting 3032 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have tried a lot of solutions but it did not work for me any guidance please.
Following is my table mapping
[image]

I have inherited an entity from this table which is having following mapping

[image]

Getting following error
[image]

If add mapping in PolicyType like this
[image]

Then get this error

[image]

Any idea how i can get rid from this error I'm stuck from last 2 days.

Comment: Did you try viewing the XML and then removing the condition from the xml on line 497 ?

Comment: Are you talking about ssdl file configuration?

Comment: follow this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/kk-KZ/adodotnetentityframework/thread/82e1dc51-3be0-4958-92ac-01fa548cfb28) for your problem

Comment: Right click on the EDMX , click on Open with and select XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first exception complains about multiple entity in the same Table-per-hierarchy inheritance without distinct condition - make sure that you set unique filter on `PolicyType` (or other column) for every entity in inheritance tree.

The second exception complains about mapping column used for condition to a property. Once you use any column for condition you cannot have it mapped to property (except the situation when the condition is `IsNull=False`). The column is already used to map entity type and no column can be used in mapping twice.

Comment: Sory but can you guide me where i am doing mapping twice?

Comment: You are using `PolicyType` for both property and condition.

Comment: you mean to say either used in Rule table or other table am i right?

Comment: Yes you cannot map it in both parent and child but you also cannot map it in child twice (to property and condition).